# Rails string in the url to be readable by application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I feel like this is simpler than I'm making it...basically, I'm wanting to give urls a parameter that is readable by my template view to display dynamic information. So, in example, if the url is:

```
www.myawesomesite.com/page/3?special_key=123
```

And my view would look something like:

```
<% if @special_key.present? && @special_key == 123 %>
Special Info!
<% end %>
```

Basically, how would I tell my rails app that 'special_key' is something it should look for as a parameter in the url?  What do I add to the 'page' controller?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<% if params[:special_key] == '123' %>
  Special Info!
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters come in controller's action in a `params` `hash`. So you only need to pass `special_key` as key.

```
@special_key = params[:special_key]
```